# App crashes when updating UI after Shared Preferences were changed

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, ui-thread

In my Activity's onCreate method I register an onSharedPreferenceChangeListener. The activity itself implements the OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener.

When the preferences are updated, the following methods are called.

```
@Override
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
    if(key.equals(Configuration.PREF_TIMETABLE_UPDATING)){
        resetView();
    }

}

public void resetView(){
    this.container.removeAllViews();
}
```

This code removes all views from a container view after a certain property has been updated. It works all right with my Android 4 devices, but on my Android 2.2.1 device the app crashes:

```
03-24 16:09:00.054: E/AndroidRuntime(1712): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #5
03-24 16:09:00.054: E/AndroidRuntime(1712): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
03-24 16:09:00.054: E/AndroidRuntime(1712):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
03-24 16:09:00.054: E/AndroidRuntime(1712):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
03-24 16:09:00.054: E/AndroidRuntime(1712):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
03-24 16:09:00.054: E/AndroidRuntime(1712):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
03-24 16:09:00.054: E/AndroidRuntime(1712):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
03-24 16:09:00.054: E/AndroidRuntime(1712):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
03-24 16:09:00.054: E/AndroidRuntime(1712):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
03-24 16:09:00.054: E/AndroidRuntime(1712):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1102)
03-24 16:09:00.054: E/AndroidRuntime(1712): Caused by: android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
03-24 16:09:00.054: E/AndroidRuntime(1712):     at android.view.ViewRoot.checkThread(ViewRoot.java:2824)
03-24 16:09:00.054: E/AndroidRuntime(1712):     at android.view.ViewRoot.requestLayout(ViewRoot.java:598)
03-24 16:09:00.054: E/AndroidRuntime(1712):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:8126)
03-24 16:09:00.054: E/AndroidRuntime(1712):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:8126)
03-24 16:09:00.054: E/AndroidRuntime(1712):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:8126)
03-24 16:09:00.054: E/AndroidRuntime(1712):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:8126)
03-24 16:09:00.054: E/AndroidRuntime(1712):     at android.widget.ScrollView.requestLayout(ScrollView.java:1200)
03-24 16:09:00.054: E/AndroidRuntime(1712):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:8126)
03-24 16:09:00.054: E/AndroidRuntime(1712):     at android.view.ViewGroup.removeAllViews(ViewGroup.java:2263)
03-24 16:09:00.054: E/AndroidRuntime(1712):     at com.example.TimetableActivity.resetView(TimetableActivity.java:430)
03-24 16:09:00.054: E/AndroidRuntime(1712):     at com.example.TimetableActivity.onSharedPreferenceChanged(TimetableActivity.java:557)
03-24 16:09:00.054: E/AndroidRuntime(1712):     at android.app.ContextImpl$SharedPreferencesImpl$EditorImpl.commit(ContextImpl.java:2869)
03-24 16:09:00.054: E/AndroidRuntime(1712):     at com.example.MyHelper.setTimetableUpdate(MyHelper.java:145)
03-24 16:09:00.054: E/AndroidRuntime(1712):     at com.example.webservice.task.LessonFetcherTask.doInBackground(LessonFetcherTask.java:33)
03-24 16:09:00.054: E/AndroidRuntime(1712):     at com.example.webservice.task.LessonFetcherTask.doInBackground(LessonFetcherTask.java:1)
03-24 16:09:00.054: E/AndroidRuntime(1712):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
03-24 16:09:00.054: E/AndroidRuntime(1712):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
03-24 16:09:00.054: E/AndroidRuntime(1712):     ... 4 more
```

How do I make sure the method called by the OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener runs on the UI thread? Any help on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that somehow you have wandered onto a new Thread:

```
Caused by: android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

One way to ensure UI commands are on the UI Thread is to use the UI Handler. (It's not as hard as it sounds.)  Simply put `removeViews()` inside a Runnable and use `post()` on any View. Like so:

Create a Runnable:

```
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        resetView();
    }
};
```

Post it to the UI Thread:

```
if(key.equals(Configuration.PREF_TIMETABLE_UPDATING)){
    container.post(runnable);
}
```